# How to locate an element inside iFrame using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, webdriverwait

This is the ifram source code:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" class="credit-card-iframe mt1 u-full-width prl2-sm" src="https://paymentcc.nike.com/services/default?id=3f42d8c5-74ee-4d08-95aa-bb6ea4949f9f&amp;ctx=checkout&amp;language=en-GB&amp;maskerEnabled=true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" xpath="1"></iframe>
```

This is the element i want;

```
<input maxlength="20" class="mod-ncss-input ncss-input pt2-sm pr4-sm pb2-sm pl4-sm" id="creditCardNumber" onautocomplete="off" value="" type="tel" tabindex="0" data-shortname="cc">
```

This is my code:

```
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='credit-card-iframe mt1 u-full-width prl2-sm']"))
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
card = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='creditCardNumber']")
card.send_keys("35663565444")
```

This is the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='creditCardNumber']"}
```

Also if I have to scroll on a page to see something can the element still be picked up thanks.

Comment: can u check if DOM is having nested iframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so to invoke `click()` on the element you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890)::

  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@sandbox='allow-scripts allow-same-origin' and contains(@class, 'credit-card-iframe')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='creditCardNumber' and @data-shortname='cc']"))).send_keys("35663565444")
    ```
  - **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't properly waiting for the element.
Do not ever use implicit waits, but instead try the followig:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import visibility_of_element_located

CARD_INPUT_LOCATOR = By.ID, "creditCardNumber"
card_input = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(visibility_of_element_located(CARD_INPUT_LOCATOR))
card_input.send_keys("35663565444")
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: *Make sure you had done 'borwser.switch_to.default_content()' before trying those