# Unable to detect div elements on a chat widget

Tags: python, web-scraping, spyder

I'm not able to detect any element on a chat widget on a social media platform called Xing

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element


    <body>
  <iframe
    id="stm"
    sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms"
    style="
      top: -510px;
      left: -320px;
      width: 320px;
      height: 510px;
      border: 0;
      position: absolute;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
    "
    src="https://stan.xing.com/stm-v1.html"
  ></iframe>
  <div data-mountpoint="" data-mounted="">
    <div class=""></div>
    <div>
      <div
        class="global-messenger-global-messenger-container-ac62c0ed global-messenger-global-messenger-disableTooltips-f506d33d"
      >
        <div class="messenger-messenger-container-da47da0a">
          <div class="routes-routes-routes-ff773e50">
            <div class="routes-panels-slider-c31e126c">
              <section
                class="panel-panel-panel-fa0d5e23 panel-panel-large-aaaf431d panel-panel-right-e9b8a32b"
              >
                <div class="panel-container-panel-container-panel-a10e3720">
                  <div class="panel-header-panel-header-container-d3dd4e5d">
                    <header
                      class="panel-header-panel-header-header-dee530f7 panel-header-panel-header-back-bb625de3"
                    >
                      <button aria-label="Back" class="ti9d8l-1 ffgOpF">
                        <div class="ti9d8l-3 iEWnsZ">
                          <span class="ti9d8l-0 kARzis"
                            ><svg
                              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                              width="24"
                              height="24"
                            >
                              <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                                <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
                                <path
                                  d="M9.293 6.293L3.586 12l5.707 5.707 1.414-1.414L7.415 13H20v-2H7.415l3.292-3.293-1.414-1.414z"
                                  fill="currentColor"
                                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                                ></path>
                              </g></svg></span
                          ><span class="ti9d8l-5 jhnZcM"></span>
                        </div>
                      </button>
                      <div
                        class="presentational-chat-header-chatHeader-ebc4be2a"
                      >
                        <div
                          class="presentational-chat-header-content-ad857131"
                        >
                          <div>
                            <div
                              class="bxaaz5-0 dVlrPm presentational-chat-header-image-d590364d presentational-chat-header-pointer-a02a7537"
                            >
                              <div class="vaubmx-0 fLLXVu">
                                <svg
                                  viewBox="0 0 256 256"
                                  class="vaubmx-3 ecqtKp"
                                >
                                  <path
                                    class="strokeWidth"
                                    d="M18.947 18.947C5.627 32.267 1 61.517 1 128s4.626 95.732 17.947 109.053C32.267 250.373 61.517 255 128 255s95.732-4.626 109.053-17.947C250.373 223.733 255 194.483 255 128s-4.626-95.732-17.947-109.053C223.733 5.627 194.483 1 128 1S32.268 5.626 18.947 18.947z"
                                    fill="transparent"
                                    stroke="transparent"
                                    vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"
                                  ></path>
                                </svg>
                                <div class="vaubmx-1 eahksz">
                                  <img
                                    alt="Stefan Wieners"
                                    title="Stefan Wieners"
                                    aria-label="Stefan Wieners"
                                    src="https://profile-images.xing.com/images/173faeb3ba2d06d14d742549fc927e46-8/stefan-wieners.64x64.jpg"
                                    class="vaubmx-2 eIWMUv"
                                  />
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="presentational-chat-header-text-e831a9f1">
                            <div>
                              <h2
                                class="sc-1gpssxl-0 jHnmMW presentational-chat-header-heading-b2bd1a01 presentational-chat-header-pointer-a02a7537 presentational-chat-header-link-f3bf4130"
                              >
                                Stefan Wieners
                              </h2>
                            </div>
                            <p
                              class="presentational-chat-header-description-c20c70f2 presentational-chat-header-pointer-a02a7537"
                            >
                              Geschäftsführer
                            </p>
                            <p
                              class="presentational-chat-header-subtitle-edbc3205 presentational-chat-header-pointer-a02a7537"
                            >
                              <span>webbytes.de GmbH</span>
                            </p>
                          </div>
                          <div
                            class="presentational-chat-header-buttons-c3a53944"
                          >
                            <div class="src-ModalContainer-base-ba1fb888">
                              <button
                                aria-label="Options"
                                class="ti9d8l-1 ffgOpF"
                              >
```

I need to click that last button in the above html snippet:

```
<button
    aria-label="Options"
    class="ti9d8l-1 ffgOpF"
>
```

Using `selenium` and `webdriver` I copy the `xPath` of the button, but it never found.
tried will all elements on chat widget, any help? Should I switch to iframe? if yes how to do that?

Comment: You mean these kind of things? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60218231/how-to-locate-an-element-inside-iframe-using-selenium-and-python or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69031921/python-selenium-access-element-inside-of-iframe

Comment: Yes, tried that. got timout exception